# Fresnel shader excluding one axis

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to get an outline like effect shown on the right [in this video](https://streamable.com/3ykogk). Using fresnel seems to make the whole thing go white at certain angles. How do I prevent that?
I'm using amplify to make this. Here's my current setup
[image: current setup]

Comment: Where is that video from? Do you have any leads for the source of the effect on the right?

Comment: The video was something i made a while back. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/EZrVpv5) the setup for that. The problem with this is that when the object is rotated on the Y axis the effect breaks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! this is the setup I used
[image: Node setup]

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a description of what you changed and why, so a reader can learn from your process.